# Insertar una imagen en un formato con dos columas

Tags: latex

Estoy escribiendo un documento en dos columnas pero dentro del texto no puedo agregar imagenes, ¿Hay alguna forma de arreglarlo?, lo que estoy escribiendo es de la siguiente forma:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics{ }{ }
\caption{ }
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que la figura ocupe el ancho de la página (doble columna), todo funciona "casi" normalmente si usas el entorno `figure*`, con asterisco. El único problema es que la figura te la pasará siempre a la página siguiente.

Si quieres que ocupe una sola columna, por desgracia es necesario recurrir a "trampas", como definir tu propio entorno (`Figura` por ejemplo) que cree una `minipage`, y además hacer uso del paquete `caption` si quieres que lleve un pie de figura numerado. Este paquete te permite meter "captions" en sitios donde normalmente LaTeX no los esperaría (como en el entorno `Figura` que hemos creado).

Ejemplo mínimo:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % Para crear texto de relleno

\newenvironment{Figura}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{Figura}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{Figura de ejemplo}
    \label{fig}
\end{Figura}

\lipsum[2]
Ver Figura~\ref{fig}.

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Usando `wrapfig`

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}

Algun texto aleatorio ...

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.9\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{}
    \caption{Test}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```